# My jokes may not make you smile, but at least my name will

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Stolen from babies as soon as I'm born,
Right from my maker by force I am torn

Pale at first, weak, and infirm,
Oh how I'll change in my ultimate form.

Billions of creatures will toil away
Changing me subtly, day after day.

I will be ready, it won't take too long
And then I'll be sharp, and I will be strong

I can be orange, yellow, or blue
And that will be it, that's the last clue.

Comment: Good to see some old riddle style again!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I think it is

> Cheese

Stolen from babies as soon as I'm born, 
Right from my maker by force I am torn

> Normally babies would drink milk, or milk gets taken away from the cows. Credits to [bg6471](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25277/bg6471) and [that2guy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/26896/that2guy)

Pale at first, weak, and infirm, 
Oh how I'll change in my ultimate form.

> Cheese is made from milk, and is mostly white and does not have a shape.

Billions of creatures will toil away 
Changing me subtly, day after day.

> It could mean the cultures, or living bacteria that changes the lactose in the milk, turning it into lactic acid.

I will be ready, it won't take too long 
And then I'll be sharp, and I will be strong

> Sharp cheese(acidic natural tasting cheese), it has a strong taste

I can be orange, yellow, or blue 
And that will be it, that's the last clue.

> I think it refers to the different type of cheese or it's color.

also the title,

> A person says Cheese! when a picture of him is being taken, hence the smiling part of the title.

Comment: I think you got it. The first paragraph is about what it's made of and where that originally comes from, normally babies would get this, but it's stolen from the maker by force

Comment: 'Right from my maker by force I am torn'. Maybe it means that the milk gets taken away from the cows?

Comment: "sharp" could also point at sharp edges of cheese in its 'ultimate form'

Comment: @Foami this should be right as it suits the title. A person says ***CHEESE!!*** when a picture of him is being taken, hence the smiling part of the title. Add this for extra rep.

Comment: And people usually groan at cheesy jokes - not laugh!

Comment: First think that came to my mind after reading the title :)

Comment: Woah, didn't expect this one to be so popular. Usually I get under 10 upvotes. I guess people around here really like cheese! Can't blame them, it's pretty damn delicious.

Comment: also jokles may be cheesey and not get a smile

Answer (score 8):

I think the answer is:

> Republican Presidential Candidate Donald Trump

*My jokes may not make you smile, but at least my name will*

> You are probably not amused by his clownish persona, "blood coming out of her whatever", etc.  But his last name is British slang for flatulence, so there's that.

*Stolen from babies as soon as I'm born*

> From the moment his political career was "born" he has been nothing but trite and juvenile.

*Right from my maker by force I am torn*

> His "maker" is the American conservative establishment, which has been pushing for more extreme rightist positions since the Obama era.  Trumpism was "torn" away from the Establishment because he, the professional Trump University scammer and carnival barker, plays their xenophobic and misogynist game much more convincingly than they ever could.

*Pale at first, weak, and infirm,
Oh how I'll change in my ultimate form.*

> Nobody thought he could win, with a base of middle-aged and senior-citizen white males.  But he has become a force to be reckoned with.  In his "ultimate form" he will be either the golf-promoter-in-chief, the President-in-name-only, shaking down foreign dignitaries and billionaire lobbyists to patronize his luxury resorts while a flyover-state governor is actually running the country; or, he will go down in flames, after having destroyed the careers of numerous Republican politicians and unleashed a wave of nativist and protectionist sentiment that will permanently commandeer the party.

*Billions of creatures will toil away
Changing me subtly, day after day.*

> According to his own inner circle, his candidacy was started merely to drive up ratings for his next reality TV venture.  But now, millions and billions of people are transforming him into a formidable political movement, by listening to his ravings as if they are actual policy proposals.  For example, with his racist rants about the Mexican-American judge, intended solely to distract blue-collar voters from the merits of the lawsuit and how he cheated people like them.  Rather than ignoring his anti-judge bile, people were speculating about what that might mean for Supreme Court vacancies filled by a Trump administration.

*I will be ready, it won't take too long
And then I'll be sharp, and I will be strong*

> His PR fluffers have been telling us that he will pivot, he will professionalize, any day now....

*I can be orange, yellow, or blue*

> He is orange, he whips up hysteria like a "yellow-bellied coward" or a "yellow journalist", and he rants and raves ("I have to rant and rave or you will fall asleep on me!") until he is blue in the face.

*And that will be it, that's the last clue.*

> Trump, for all his bluster, is a bit of an enigma, who holds cards close to the chest.  He has no friends.

Comment: Is this intended to be a humorous answer?

Comment: I think this is good. And funny.. :)

Answer (score -1):

The answer is

> umbilical cord. It's torn down from babies as soon as they are born, and then all other things about it matches its description in the riddle.

Comment: Please add the other explanations.